# Return file to state before git pull

Tags: git

I want to return a file to the state it was before I did git pull which had conflicts (so I can then commit it).

This is how the file looks after git pull had conflicts:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
<!-- nothing to see here -->
=======
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-123"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
>>>>>>> 6c10038924468105df6c32255f38c51167b355ba
```

Would I be correct in thinking that before i did the pull the file looked like this:

```
<!-- nothing to see here -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
your local file state
=======
changes that caused conflict and come from outer branch that you try to merge
>>>>>>> 6c10038924468105df6c32255f38c51167b355ba commit hash from outer branch
```

**Q**: Would I be correct in thinking that before i did the pull the file looked like this: `<!-- nothing to see here -->`

**A**: yes

Comment: If i reset it to previous commit then i lose uncomitted changes?  I want to make file like it was before i dit git pull, NOT go back to previous commit

Comment: I want to reset neither file to the previous commit, i want to restore it to the state it was at before the git pull with uncomitted changes.  I even pasted in my question what i think it should be, I just need an yes or no whether I got it right.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

**How do I revert changes introduced by a specific commit?**

When you need to undo something you’ve committed, you have a couple of good options. Both of the options below will only affect the current HEAD, so be sure to confirm that you have the intended branch checked out.

**Revert**

As it sounds, the revert command changes all the files for a specific commit back to their state before that commit was completed. Specify the commit that you want to revert:

```
git revert <commit_ID>
```

It’s important to note the mechanics of this command. The reverted commit is not deleted. Rather, Git creates a new commit with the included files reverted to their previous state.
So your version control history moves forward while the state of your files moves backwards.

**Reset**

This option is a little different than a revert. It resets the status of your repo (working HEAD) to an older revision. It’s a true rollback of the state of your repo.

```
git reset --hard <commit_ID>
```

When you use this option, Git discards any commits between the current state of the repo and the target commit. The branch will then appear to stop at the commit you reset the HEAD to.